# iOS - build email URL without parsing

Tags: ios, nsurl

I want to build an email URL using some class (NSURL or similar) **BUT** I do not want the overhead of parsing a string. I want to be able to specify the scheme (`mailto` in this case) and the address (`someone@somewhere.com` in this case.)

I've tried this code:

```
NSString *address = @"someone@somewhere.com";
NSString *scheme = @"mailto";

NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithScheme:scheme host:address path:@"/"];
NSLog(@"test2: %@", [url absoluteString]);
```

but it outputs:

```
mailto://someone@somewhere.com/
```

which isn't even a valid email URL.

What are my options?

p.s. please don't suggest using NSDataDetector because it is even more expensive than the usual kind of string parsing.

Comment: Would be interesting to know why you are targeting a "highly optimised" solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you do have purely the email address and no other paraphernalia, the solution is simple:

```
- (NSURL *)mailtoURLWithEmailAddress:(NSString *)address;
{
  address = [address stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  NSURL *result = [NSURL URLWithString:[@"mailto:" stringByAppendingString:address]];
  return result;
}
```

Adding percent escapes is important should there be any chance that somebody might specify an address outside of the ASCII characters, or include one of the reserved URL characters.

For a more capable solution, see `KSMailtoURLs` in my [KSFileUtilities](https://github.com/karelia/KSFileUtilities) repository. It adds:

- Handling of strings that include the recipient's name, as well as address
- Encoding of email subject line etc.